# Mocking Twig_Environment

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, twig, phpunit

I want to mock a `Twig_Environment` for phpUnit So on my test I called:

```
   $twigMock=$this->getMockBuilder(\Twig_Environment::class)
                            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                            ->getMock()
                            ->method('render')
                            ->willReturn('');
```

Then I have a class:

```
class SampleClass
{
    private $twig=null;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
      $this->twig=$twig;
    }

    public function foo($param)
    {
       if(param)
       {
          $content=$this->twig->render('some_template./html.twig');
       }
       // DO other stuff
    }
}
```

But when I try to call on my test class:

```
$campleClassInstance=new SampleClass($twigMock);
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to \SampleClass::__construct() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, instance of PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker given,

Do you haver any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing setting the variable to the return value of `willReturn` which doesn't return the original mock object but rather an `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker` object that PHPUnit uses internally.  You can't chain the mock and the expectation together in order for this to work.  Change your mocking to:

```
$twigMock=$this->getMockBuilder(\Twig_Environment::class)
                        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                        ->getMock();

$twigMock->method('render')
         ->willReturn('');
```

Answer (score 4):

In symfony 4.4, the Environment class can't be mocked:

Class "Twig\TemplateWrapper" is declared "final" and cannot be mocked.